# Integration of mathematical notation in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, mathjax, tex, typesetting

## Background

TeX-based macros can be used to typeset equations in HTML using [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

This can produce output such as: **∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup> i² = (n²+n)(2n+1)/6**

**For example:**

Here is HTML content that uses MathJax to typeset an equation in HTML:

```
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
$$x = {\sqrt{2^2-4ac}}$$
$$x = {\sqrt{x+y}}$$
</body>
</html>
```

**And:**

```
<body>
<math display="block" xmlns="&mathml;">
<mrow>
<mstyle mathsize="170%">
  <msqrt>
    <mi>&alpha;</mi>
    <mi>&beta;</mi>
    <mi>&gamma;</mi>
    <mi>&Gamma;</mi>
    <mi>&theta;</mi>
    <mi>&omicron;</mi>
    <mi>&omicron;</mi>
    <mi>&tau;</mi>
  <mrow>
    <mn><input type="text" size="4"></mn>
    <mo>*</mo>
    <mi>x</mi>
  </mrow>

<mroot>
  <mi>x</mi>
  <mn>3</mn>
</mroot>

  <mi>x</mi>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mi>y</mi>


  </msqrt>
</mstyle>
</mrow>
</math>
</body>
```

## Question

Is it possible to typeset equations in reports using iReport (or Jaspersoft Studio)?

That is, how can mathematical formula be written into a report?

Comment: Mathematical induction is that if you have a statement A(n) that depends on an integer n, then proving A(0) and A(n)=>A(n+1) proves that statement for all natural integers n.

Comment: @umarfaraz Your question is totally unclear

Comment: Did you try styling? Did you find how do it with html, for example?

Comment: You should post the code (*jrxml* file) you have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129348/discussion-between-umar-faraz-and-alex-k).

Comment: It is not looks like a *jrxml* file. You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40863564/edit) the question - to post the *jrxml* file to reproduce the problem you faced

Comment: @DaveJarvis Original question did not contain any information about using MathJax :)

Comment: Maybe you can export SVG and then embed it into your report.